# m2e API for importing projects

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

We are adding a wizard in Eclipse that creates a hierarchy of maven projects in the file system. Then we want to import them into the workspace through the M2E API, so the connectors are invoked and the Eclipse configuration is updated.
What is the best way for doing this? I found some APIs but they seem to be "internal".

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you're trying to do correctly, I'm not sure why you're adding a wizard. This can be done through the Maven Eclipse Integration via File -> Import -> Existing Maven Projects and selecting the root pom in your project hierarchy.

http://eclipse.org/m2e/

Comment: The wizard is actually generating a project hierarchy based on (complex) parameters, like a maven archetype. Once this is generated, then I'd like to automate the import

Comment: Ah, I've done something like that in the past with archetypes. Unfortunately I'm not aware of details or requirements for import automation.